# Correctness of proof that an ordered field S that has the supremum property also has the infimum property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

First question I have is how would you describe the relationship between an ordered field and an ordered set and continue the proof by treating the field as a set?  I want to say that right in the beginning to make things clear but I don't know how to say it.

Here's the rest of the proof:

Let A be a nonempty subset of S s.t.  it is bounded above and D be the set of all lower bounds for A.
Fix a to be elements of A.  Then for each d in subset D d is a lower bound for A so d $\leq$ a  for all a in A.

Since d is bounded above by A it has the supremum $\gamma$ .  Since every a is an upper bound for d, $\gamma \leq a$ for each element a in subset A.  So $\gamma$ is a lower bound for A and is clearly an infimum since it is an upper bound for the set of lower bounds.

Comment: So far no progress towards a proof. Use the fact that $x\le y$ if and only if $-y\le -x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: This looks like progress to me, if you change "bounded above" in the third paragraph to "bonded below". matsmv is saying, the set $D$ of lower bounds of $A$ is bounded above, so it has a supremum; and this supremum of $D$ is the infimum of $A$.

Comment: I was wrong in my comment above, which I am tempted to erase but won't.

Answer (score 1):

This argument is on the right track but the assumption that $A$ is bounded above is irrelevant.  You need to assume $A$ is bounded below, so that the set $D$ of all lower bounds of $A$ is non-empty.  Then you can apply the supremum property to the set $D$.

(André Nicolas is usually right, but he is too pessimistic this time.)

Comment: I think the idea was right; "bounded above" looks like a typo for "bounded below".

Comment: So how would you connect the relationship between the ordered set and the ordered field? And how will the supremum property be assumed if we assume A is bounded below?

Comment: Oh. To echo André's comment: I was wrong in my comment above, which I am tempted to erase but won't.

Comment: Is the relationship as simple as: F is an ordered set, which is also a field?  If so, how would you edit this proof?

Comment: @matsmv: What you are trying to prove is that every non-empty set that is bounded below has a greatest lower bound, given that every non-empty set that is bounded above has a smallest upper bound.  So you need to assume a set is non-empty and bounded below, and then prove that it has a greatest lower bound.  The way you do that involves looking at the smallest upper bound of the set of all lower bounds.

Comment: So aside from the bounded below part that needs to be corrected is there anything else wrong with it?

Comment: It looks ok besides that, but I'd have phrased the last sentence a bit differently: clearly the largest lower bound since it is the suprememum of the set of all lower bounds.